# How do I share purchased iOS apps without my Mac?

Tags: ios, applications, sharing

Is there a way someone else can share a purchased iOS app with me when I only have my iOS device with me but no Mac but the other person has both his Mac and his iOS device around?

Is there also a way when we both only have our iOS device around?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assuming they haven't run out of authorizations, they can sign into the app store on your iOS device and download the apps they wish to "share".

Just go to the preferences app, Store and sign in another Apple ID.

You'll have that app to run until you erase it or the whole device. It of course won't transfer that app to a computer where your friend hasn't authorized iTunes, but iOS will be happy to run that version of the app indefinitely.

Comment: What does that actually mean "they haven't run out of authorization"? What is an authorization and how many does a person have?

Comment: Also: How on earth can someone else login in to iTunes on my device. I don't see any login form in iTunes for the credentials anywhere on iTunes.

Comment: I might be confusing the basic sign in for the app store with the automatic purchase download or the music side of things where Apple counts the number of authorized devices. Perhaps I should say - if they can log in, it will work.

Comment: Looks like someone else can log into the appstore on my device, not iTunes: http://gigaom.com/apple/quick-tip-sharing-iphone-and-ipad-apps-on-the-go/